# Dynamically changing javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I am making an AJAX calling using JQuery.  I get back a JSON object containing HTML and Javascript.  Within the javascript, there is a function Initialize().  This returned javascript from the AJAX call should replace the initial definition of Initialize() which was there before the AJAX call was made.  So basically, I'm trying to dynamically change the code of the javascript function to code I get back from an AJAX call.  Help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? Did you try something and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
init = function() { alert("init"); };

hash = { "newInit" : function() { alert("newInit"); }};

init(); // alerts "init"

init = hash.newInit;

init(); // alerts "newInit"
```

Comment: Ah...function pointers.  Don't know why I didn't think of that :D  Yes, this definitely helps.  Thanks!